# Is $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x\leq 1,y\leq1,-1\leq z\leq 1\}$ a star domain?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, elementary-set-theory

> Is $\mathbb{R}^3\setminus\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x\leq1,y\leq1,-1\leq z\leq1\}$ a star domain.

**My approach:**

Let be $N:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid x\leq1,y\leq 1,-1\leq z \leq1\}$ and $M:=\mathbb{R}^3\setminus N$ and $a\in M$ such that $a_3>1$ and $b=(0,0,1)\in N$.

We define $S_{a,b}:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}^3$ by $S_{a,b}(t):=a+(b-a)t$. We are looking for a $t_0$ such that $a_3+(1-a_3)t_0<-1$. For example $t_0:=\frac{2a_3+2}{a_3-1}$ satifies this requirement. Hence, the vector
$$
c:=S_{a,b}(t_0)=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1-a_1t_0\\a_2-a_2t_0\\-a_3-2<-1
\end{pmatrix}\notin N.
$$
Next we define $S_{a,c}:[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}^3$ by $S_{a,c}(t):=a+t(c-a)$ and see that
$$
S_{a,c}\left(\frac{a_3-1}{2a_3+2}\right)=\begin{pmatrix}
a_1\\a_2\\a_3\end{pmatrix}+\frac{a_3-1}{2a_3+2} \begin{pmatrix}
-a_1\frac{2a_3+2}{a_3-1}\\-a_2\frac{2a_3+2}{a_3-1}\\-2a_3-2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
0\\0\\1
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
This means that the line Segment $S_{a,c}$ is not a subset of $M$. We can conduct the same arguing if we consider $a\in M$ such that $a_3<-1$. Finally, this shows that no point can be used as a *star point*. Consequently $M$ is not a star domain.

---

Is my approach correct? It seems to me that this kind of proofs are very error prone and I am wondering if there are shorter ways, that do not require more sophisticated methods, to prove that $M$ is not a star domain?

Comment: Quick note from a passerby. Not sure I follow the logic and geometric idea of the argument: (i) Is the point $a$ a prospective arbitrary center? What are the purposes of $b$ and $c$? (ii) If the guess about $a$ is right, don't we need to check the case $-1 < a_3 < 1$ (and $a_1$, $a_2 > 1$)? <> No need to address either, just noting what I don't understand after a couple of readings. ;)

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang, Yes $a$ should be a possible center point and I forgot the cases where $a_1,a_2>1$ and $-1\leq a_3\leq1$. Thanks for the remark :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call your set $U$, and suppose $(x,y,z) \in U$ can be used as base point.

If $z\neq 0$, take the line that passes through the origin and $(x,y,z)$, that is, $$f(t)=(tx,ty,tz), \quad t\in\mathbb{R}$$ As $(0,0,0)\notin U$, this line is not contained in $U$. Nonetheless, taking a sufficiently large $t_0<0$, the $z$-component of $f(t_0)$ is greater in magnitude than $1$, and thus $f(t_0)\in U$. For this reason, the segment joining $(x,y,z)$ and $f(t_0)$ is not contained in $U$.

If $z=0$ then take the line that passes through $(1,1,1)\notin U$ and $(x,y,z)=(x,y,0)$. Using a similar reasoning as before you can find a point in $U$ such that the segment joining it and $(x,y,z)$ is not contained in $U$.

This argument may be generalized to an arbitrary non-star domain.

Comment: Hey Julio! Yes I think your reasoning is a bit faster :) Two remarks: 1.) the line segment required by the definition of a star domain is defined on the interval $[0,1]$, so you should make a case dinstinction with regard to $z>0$ and $z<0$. 2.) If $z=0$ then either $x\neq 0$ or $y\neq 0$. WLOG $x\neq0$. Again we must consider two cases $x>0$ and $x<0$ to properly apply your argument. But maybe you had beared this already in mind.

Comment: Yes, I just pointed out the idea ;)

Answer (score 0):

A simpler approach might be as follows.  Assume for the sake of contradiction that $a\in M$ is a center.  Now find a pair of points $(0,0,1+\epsilon)\in M$ and $(0,0,-1-\epsilon)\in M$ such that at least one is not visible from $a$.

Comment: Maybe I did not fully understand you idea, but I don't see how this approach is simpler. If you carry it out thorougly you end up, like me with several case distinctions, except that you've chosen different points.